# Is there any difference in metrics when Querying the data using Eloqua API vs Getting a report from Eloqua Insights?

Tags: oracle, cloud, eloqua

I am validating the data from Eloqua insights with the data I pulled using  Eloqua API. There are some differences in the metrics.So, are there any issues when pulling the data using API vs .csv file using Eloqua Insights?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, besides undocumented data discrepancies that might exist, Insights can aggregate, calculate, and expose various hidden relations between data in Eloqua that is not accessible by an  API export definition.

Think of the api as the raw data with the ability to pick and choose fields and apply a general filter on those, but Insights/OBIEE as a way to calculate that data, create those relationships across tables of raw data, and then present it in a consumable manner to the end user. A user has little use with a 1 gigabyte csv of individual unsubscribes for the past year, but present that in several graphs on a dashboard with running totals, averages, and timeseries, and it suddenly becomes actionable.